# Filter not working as expected for Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

My Elastic search document look like this :

```
{
    "_index": "terms",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "30028861",
    "_version": 36,
    "_seq_no": 338988,
    "_primary_term": 6,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "title": {
            "value": "Credit Card Number",
            "is_changed": false
        },
        "node_id": 30028861,
        "domain_id": 30028838,

        "node_name": "Credit Card Number",
        "parent_id": 30028839,
        "term_name": "Credit Card Number",
        "account_id": 30028807,
       
        "published_status": "Published",
        "published_status_id": "PUB",
        "node_sub_type": "TRM",
    }
}
```

And I am trying to add **Filter clause** with **must_not** condition

My query is :

```
{
   "from":0,
   "size":10,
   "track_total_hits":true,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "account_id":30028807
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":[
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "terms":{
                           "domain_id":[
                              30119066,
                              30123338
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "terms":{
                           "parent_id":[
                              30028839
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "must_not":[
                     {
                        "terms":{
                           "published_status_id":[
                              "PUB"
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "terms":{
                           "published_status":[
                              "Published"
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "must_not":{
            "terms":{
               "published_status.raw":[
                  "Disabled"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "_source":[
      "node_type",
      "node_id",
      "parent_name",
      "table_name"
   ]
}
```

So As In must_not mentioned that if published_status_id in PUB and published_status  in Published  document should not return but it is returning all docs with containing both .  whole intention to use filter clause is either domain_id and parent_id found  and  published_status_id Not in PUB and published_status  Not  in Published. but it's returning status with PUB

Comment: Provide your mapping. I think published_status_id and published_status arent keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have `published_status.raw` which is probably a `keyword`, and thus,  `published_status` is probably a `text` field. In light of this, the clause in the `must_not` should probably be

```
                                       add this
                 {                        |
                    "terms":{             v
                       "published_status.raw":[
                          "Published"
                       ]
                    }
                 }
```

And also make sure to check `published_status_id` which might suffer from the same issue, you might need to use `published_status_id.raw` in order to make an exact `terms` match.